# Extracting large files with zipfile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm trying to extract a zip file of 1.23 GB with `zipFile` library. But it gives the following error:

```
 compression type 9 (deflate64)
```

Here's my code:

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(newPath)
```

It gives error while trying to extract the contents.

Is there any way to unzip large zip files with Python?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because that compression method is not implemented in the `zipfile` module.

Some discussion about the issue is  here: https://bugs.python.org/issue14313

The fix was to raise a `NotImplementedError` instead of adding support for the compression method.

Suggested solutions:

- If possible, recompress the file using a standard deflate method.
- Use the `subprocess` module to invoke the system `unzip` command, asssuming it is installed on your OS (if it supports that compression method, I'm honestly not sure. I know that 7-zip supports the method.).

Comment: Let me get this straight. There's no way to fix this bug and the only solution is to recompress the file and use `unzip` command with `subprocess` module, which may or may not be installed in my system, instead of `extractall`?

Comment: Yes, at least this used to be the case and I haven't heard that the compression method being added. Note that the zip archive format supports pluggable compression methods, and just because you have a library that supports the archive format doesn't mean it supports all algorithms.

Comment: but why does it work for small files and not for large?

Comment: My guess: your archiving program changes method dynamically based on source input. Use `zipinfo -v zipfile.zip`  to print information about each zip file to see what method it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Microsoft Windows Explorer use Deflate64 compression when creating ZIP files larger than 2GB.(There are various methods for zipping, and it automatically switches the method based on file size).

This Deflate64 compression is not implemented in the zipfile module.
You should use the **zipfile-deflate64** module instead

Install using : `pip install zipfile-deflate64`

In your python file, import the module using `import zipfile_deflate64 as zipfile`

Now you can use it like the zipfile module:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('NameofZipFile'+ '.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(dirname)
```

For more information you can read : https://pypi.org/project/zipfile-deflate64/